# Is "more quickly" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Can you use "more quickly" in the following context?

> I can move more quickly than she can.

Comment: According to the grammar books 'more quickly' is the right way to say it. But then in speech 'quicker' is less of a mouthful than 'more quickly' and so it has now passed into common use.

Comment: But what about *quicklier* ??

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with doing something quicker.

Comment: Yes you can, especially you have what the sports world calls "good quickness" (-:

Comment: @GEdgar 'Quicklier' is what I said, did'le I !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works.

You can also say

- I can move quicker than she can.
- She moves quickly, but I can move quicker still.
- Between us, I move quickest.
- Between us, I move quicker.
- I am even quicker than she.

**Edited to Add:** Since I got a complaint and a downvote for using "quicker" and "quickest" as adverbs (when they seem nominally to be adjectives), I thought I would [put that as a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150353/can-some-words-serve-as-both-adjective-or-adverb), and garnered responses that seemed to militate strongly towards my usage here to be legitimate.  A paraphrased "Casual yet still grammatical" was the judgment of one commenter who consulted an online dictionary about adverbial use of a nominal adjective.

So I will stand by my answer, and invite the downvoter to reconsider.

**Edited further to Add:** I had never heard of the term "flat adverb" before, but @FumbleFingers directed my attention to it on [grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/grammar/adverbs/):

> "Some adverbs don’t change from their adjectival forms. These are
>   known as flat adverbs. A few of the most common ones are close, deep,
>   fast, quick, and right. Some of these have corresponding -ly adverbs
>   with which they are interchangeable—for example, come quick and come
>   quickly mean the same thing."

Comment: Nooooo ... `quick` is not an adverb, regardless of @Zzyrk's assertion regarding "common use".

Comment: Please @dg99, where did I use "quick" as an adverb?  I am very puzzled by your comment.  I wrote "quicker" and "quickest", never "quick", and those are adjectives.

Comment: Precisely.  `quicker` and `quickest` are adjectives, not adverbs, yet you applied them to the verb `move`.

Comment: @dg99 I invite you to reconsider your downvote (if it was you) in the light of responses to the question I put to ELU, which is referenced in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. you can compare adverb like adjectives for example:
fast faster fastest
high higher highest
or for more than one syllable you can use for example:
carefully   more carefully  (the) most carefully

reference:
http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/adverb_steig.htm